# Классическая задачка на определение прямоугольности треугольника

Tags: java, алгоритм, геометрия

Есть java (с которой я практически не знаком), есть три вершины треугольника (шесть int), есть необходимость проверить, прямоугольный ли треугольник. Естественно, в этом случае нужно вообще боком обойти флоаты, чтобы не нарваться на какую-нибудь разницу в E-13 при проверке. Я довольно долго пыхтел, прежде чем до меня дошло, что

- Каждая сторона - сама по себе гипотенуза прямоугольного треугольника, две вершины которого совпадают с концами этой стороны, и ее квадрат найти проще простого. Скучная картинка для наглядности:

  [image]
- В самом банальном уравнении прямоугольного треугольника и так используются квадраты сторон, поэтому точную длину стороны мне вообще не нужно знать

Задачу я таким образом вроде решил, но меня не отпускает ощущение, что я тупой и упускаю какое-то совсем банальное решение. И, соответственно, хотел бы услышать идеи по поводу решения этой задачи.

Comment: Задача действительно весьма простая. Решить ее можно как минимум двумя способами( зная школьный курс геометрии хотя бы до 10 класса ). Первый способ - по теореме Пифагора или же по теореме косинусов, например.

Comment: @0xFFh, спасибо за тонкие намеки про десятый класс. Чуть выше, собственно, и есть теорема Пифагора, а также причины, почему нельзя идти через прямое вычисление длины сторон. С косинусами, боюсь, тоже не обойдется без флоатов.

Comment: Послесловие: эта задачка была вступительным заданием в школу автоматизации процессов Яндекса, нужно было написать unit-тест, который бы проверял прямоугольность треугольника. И конкретно в этом задании была еще одна большая штука, о которой мало кто думает: кроме подтверждения особого соотношения расстояний между вершинами надо еще проверить а) что это треугольник, и все вершины не лежат на одной прямой и б) две или все три вершины не лежат в одной точке. Видимо, из-за этого мое решение и было помечено системой автобилда как "частично верное".

Comment: (и нет, я ни в коем случае не искал здесь возможности пройти за счет чужих знаний, на тот момент мое решение уже ушло, и больше я ничего не заливал)

Comment: Делитесь ещё ежедневными задачами — интересно ; )

Comment: @Sergiks, ну там обещали домашнее задание подкидывать, если будет что-то неординарное, где мне будет интересно услышать совета - появятся еще такие вопросы.

Comment: @Etki, тоже было такое задание, учел и возможное переполнение и условие (б), но не приняли. У меня нет никаких вариантов, почему, не считая отсутствия условия (а), но я проверил на бумажке - его можно не проверять, поскольку не существует точек, лежащих на одной прямой и для которых верно соотношение т. Пифагора. Можете ли как-нибудь прокомментировать?

Comment: @TheGodfather нет, вам нужно задавать этот вопрос проверяющим тест. Теорема пифагора будет верна для двух точек в одной вершине, потому что в этом случае один катет выродится в ноль, а второй станет равен гипотенузе.

Comment: Так если мы проверили условие (б), то заведомо все точки разные. А для разных точек т. Пифагора будет выполняться тогда и только тогда, когда можно построить треугольник и он прямоугольный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно проверить пару отрезков на перпендикулярность. Получить их векторы и проверить, равно ли 0 скалярное произведение векторов. Псевдокод:

```
vx1 = x2 - x1;
vy1 = y2 - y1;

vx2 = x3 - x1;
vy2 = y3 - y1;

dotProduct = vx1*vx2 + vy1*vy2;  /* == 0 ? прямой угол : не прямой */
```

В худшем случае придётся проверить все три пары.

Comment: А зачем нормализовывать? Скалярное произведение и без этого будет нулем.

Comment: @Barmaley, неверный термин, имел в виду, что перенести начало отрезков в (0,0), чтобы получить их векторы. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Есть нюанс: поскольку Вы в решении используете произведения, для достаточно больших значений координат вычисления будут некорректны. Причём, ошибки переполнения не возникнет. Об этом говорится в [спецификации языка](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html), п. 4.2.2:

> The integer operators do not indicate overflow or underflow in any way

Если в постановке задачи не оговаривается, каковы максимальные возможные значения, необходимо это предусмотреть и для вычислений применять не `int`, а [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).