# определение прямоугольного треугольника

Tags: java, junit

Здравствуйте. Нашел вопрос больше года назад –
[Классическая задачка на определение прямоугольности треугольника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/363913/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Сейчас мучаюсь с этим решением. В java новичок, тем более в прикручивании junit тестов. Отправил решение, вроде по математике верное, но вываливает ошибку.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class Test {

    private Rtriangle triangle;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Rtriangle triangle = RtriangleProvider.getRtriangle();
    }

    @After
    public void clearIt() { triangle = null; }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
        double sqab, sqbc, sqac;

        x1 = triangle.getApexX1();
        x2 = triangle.getApexX2();
        x3 = triangle.getApexX3();

        y1 = triangle.getApexY1();
        y2 = triangle.getApexY2();
        y3 = triangle.getApexY3();

        if ( (x1-x3)*(y2-y3) == (x2-x3)*(y1-y3) )  {
            System.out.println("Это не треугольник, все вершины лежат на одной прямой.");
            assertTrue(false);
        }

        sqab = (x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1);
        sqbc = (x3-x2)*(x3-x2)+(y3-y2)*(y3-y2);
        sqac = (x3-x1)*(x3-x1)+(y3-y1)*(y3-y1);

    if (sqab==sqac+sqbc || sqac==sqab+sqbc || sqbc==sqab+sqac)
        assertTrue(true);
    else {
         System.out.println("Треугольник не прямоугольный.");
        assertTrue(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Ошибка - неправильный алгоритм, но я подозреваю, что дело в некорректном использовании junit'овых инструментов. Возможно, после `assertTrue(false);` нужно как-то принудительно тест завершать?

Comment: Свой код необходимо добавить в вопрос + описать, где не работает + ошибку

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @rumm, что за класс `Rtriangle`? Какую ошибку выдаёт компилятор?

Comment: Ну так выдайте ещё и ошибку. И на каких данных она происходит.

Comment: @Arsenicum, так ошибка вроде в логике, а не в компиляторе, сказано же "отправил решение", т.е. проверяющая система (возможно, яндекса) не захотела принимать ответ

Comment: Что Ваша программа скажет про треугольник со сторонами 24000, 32000 и 40000?

Comment: Да, у меня тоже возник этот вопрос - переменные, хранящие квадраты  сторон должны быть double или long хватит?

Comment: Вываливает ошибку *неправильный алгоритм* курам на смех.

Comment: Ну да, то есть алгоритм проверки треугольника на прямоугольность - неправильный. Хотя вот она - проверка по т.Пифагора, её достаточно должно быть.

Comment: @rumm Пифагор был великий мыслитель в прошлом, когда не было компьютеров, тогда надо было решать задачи в уме, но эта задача не связана с мышлением, просто надо знать как работать с junit. Если я провильно понял вопрос двусмыссленный, то есть неопределенный.

Comment: Хорошо, что тут неправильно с точки зрения работы с junit? Я прогоняю этот код через intellij IDEA и тесты проходят успешно или нет (в зависимости от треугольников, определяемых координатами точек). Возможно, в этом коде сразу 2 теста, а не один? Как я понял, 1 метод после @Test - это один тест и есть.

Comment: @rumm Тест -  это то, что тестируют, а не то что тестируется.